# where condition based on another field value in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have table with following structure:

```
==========================================
itemName minPrice maxPrice curPrice
========================================== 
   A         10      20        8 
   B         15      25        12
   c         20      30        25
```

In mysql is like that

```
select * from Items where curPrice<minPrice
```

but i want in django which should return like "A,B item name result".

I already tried with filter but i can not get success.

Comment: did you tried ``model.objects.filter(curPrice<minPrice)``

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay please don't give code unless you actually know the solution. That syntax is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

To compare a value in a filter with another field on the model, use [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions) objects:

```
from django.db.models import F
Item.objects.filter(curPrice__lt=F('minprice'))
```

Comment: Thanks for giving answer.But i got error. Error is "Join on field 'curPrice' not permitted. Did you misspell 'le' for the lookup type?"

Comment: no __lt is right, solution looks right to me. The error might be just because you have 'minPrice' and not 'minprice' - it can be quite confusing

Comment: @Daniel Roseman.I am getting error "cannot convert value of type <class 'django.db.models.sql.expressions.SQLEvaluator'> to bson"

Comment: Are you using some kind of MongoDB backend? Is this django-nonrel? You should have mentioned that in the question. I don't even know if it's even possible to do this with nonrel.